# "set: illegal option -" on one host but not the other

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, sh

I've written a sh script in one of my ubuntu VMs which works fine, but when I try to run it in my other VMs, it does not work. Both VMs should be the same. With `bash --version` both VMs reply with:

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

With `lsb_release -a`, both also reply:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

My `security_steps.sh` script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if ! [ -f svn_up_action.sh ]; then
  echo "svn_up_action.sh is missing. Please make sure it is in the same directory as this script."
  exit
fi
```

When I do: `sudo sh security_steps.sh`, the console errors with:

```
: not foundeps.sh: 6: security_steps.sh:
security_steps.sh: 7: set: Illegal option -
```

How can I figure out what's going on with the VM of the non-working shell? I feel like the shells are somehow different. I appreciate your help!

Comment: This **isn't a bash script**, so the question shouldn't be tagged bash. `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh, not bash.

Comment: Also, your probable underlying problem is *the very first thing* that the tag wiki at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info tells you to check before asking.

Comment: ...similarly, the output of `bash --version` is **completely irrelevant** to a script that uses `#!/bin/sh` rather than `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you so much for that link! Yes there are `^M` at the end of each line

Comment: Did using `dos2unix`, the vim `:set fileformat=unix`, or a similar command resolve your problem successfully?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, `dos2unix` solved my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 50):

This almost certainly means your file has DOS newlines -- thus, hidden CR characters at the end.

Thus, `set -e` becomes `set -e$'\r'` (using bash-specific syntax to represent the CR character), which isn't a valid option.

This also explains the `: not found`, as a CR will reset the cursor to the beginning of the line, truncating an error message of the form `sh: commandname: not found` by making the `commandname` instead an operation that moves the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Comment: This is the underlying solution to the problem and this answer should be marked as accepted. I came through this problem and took about 2 hours to realize that a simple edit with VsCode on my script was placing that CR characters at the end.

Answer (score 12):

I had *.sh file throwing me this while running it on Windows (via GitBash).

I've had to change line endings to UNIX/OSX format.

Comment: This is the same thing the answer preceding it by three months said, no?

Answer (score 11):

In **Windows**:

```
choco install dos2unix
dos2unix file.sh
```

In **Linux**:

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
dos2unix file.sh
```

**dos2unix** converts the file to the Unix type.

After doing this, try to run the application again or the file.

Answer (score 9):

If you run into this problem because you are touching your files on a Windows machine, Notepad++ is your friend.

**Inspection**
View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters
Look for `CR` `LF` line endings, rather than `LF` line endings!

**Solving**
Search > Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
Make sure Search Mode is set to `Extended`
Find `\r\n` and replace with `\n`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command, it will remove the hidden CR characters

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

it is because of End of Line Sequence (`CRLF` and `LF`)
The root cause is the Windows use `\r\n` as a end-of-line, while the *nix use only `\n`.

In Windows set the End of Line Sequence on `LF`.

You can select it easily in VSCode.

Comment: i used prettier to add new line at the end of the file in vscode & it set it to `CRLF`. once i changed it to `LF`, it worked. this was in docker bdw with `run.sh` script at the end using `CMD`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Error,

Later I found that these raise because My shell script file moved from a windows machine to Linux machine(there may be a chance of formating or Encoding error).

So I have created the document in Linux machine itself. It solved the issue.

This "May" help few, I am posting this because it worked for me.