# entrypoint file not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker image with this command:

```
FROM ruby:2.4-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY Gemfile /usr/src/app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /usr/src/app/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
RUN bundle install --without development test

VOLUME /state

COPY . /usr/src/app/

ENTRYPOINT ["api-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["foreman", "start"]
```

it builds correctly but when I try to run bash, for example, I get this
`container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"api-entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"api-entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH".`

I tried copy the entrypoint file, give it executable permissions as well with `CMD`...nothing worked

Comment: I'm using `ADD` and finally setting the correct permission for my entry script i.e: `ADD entry.sh /entry.sh
RUN chmod +x /entry.sh
ENTRYPOINT /entry.sh`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

/usr/src/app may not be in your path so you should include the full path to the script. You also need to ensure that your entrypoint.sh is executable, docker will copy the permissions exactly as they are on your build host, so this step may not be needed depending on your scenario.

```
FROM ruby:2.4-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY Gemfile /usr/src/app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /usr/src/app/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
RUN bundle install --without development test

VOLUME /state

COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN chmod 755 api-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/api-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["foreman", "start"]
```

Comment: it works locally but for some reason, when deploying on Docker Cloud I keep seeing `ERROR: api-1: Container command '/usr/src/app/api-entrypoint.sh' not found or does not exist.`

Comment: Are you deploying the same image (with the same image id)?

Comment: oh, nevermind, I found the problem: alpine images, when using an entrypoint, should have `#!/bin/sh` not `#!/bin/bash`. silly mistake

Answer (score 173):

I had this problem with Docker for Windows and the solution was changing the entrypoint script file from CRLF -> LF.

Comment: Oh my effin word ... really ... works now thanks a bunch!

Comment: Wow, that's it. Thanks!!

Comment: Wow, how.... I was trying to troubleshoot this for almost an hour! Thanks!

Comment: That works! the file was created on ubuntu by another dev and I was working on the windows.

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked on Docker Desktop 2.5.0.0 (Engine 19.03.13)!

Comment: Thanks. How did you troubleshoot this?

Comment: change CRLF to LF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39532890/3176451

Comment: thanks a lot your suggestion worked,  you can simply use vs code for do same it have option in bottom right corner. to Switch between CRLF to LF and vice versa.

Comment: I also had to checkout the entrypoint file again `git checkout origin/master -- path/to/entrypoint.sh`

Comment: This almost feel surreal...

Comment: This is sooooo absurd... Thanks for this.

Comment: You´re a saint. May your code be bug free, for eternity. Thy

Comment: oh my effin word indeed. blessings unto you for bug free code forever

Comment: I was just about to give up on this but you came as savior. Bundle of Thanks

Answer (score 63):

I had the same problem - the entrypoint was not found, but I was sure that it *was* there.

It seems that you can't use single quotes `'` for the entrypoint/command.

So I changed from

```
ENTRYPOINT ['/foo/bar/script.sh']
CMD ['run']
```

to

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/foo/bar/script.sh"]
CMD ["run"]
```

and it works.

Comment: That makes a difference. Thanks!

Comment: this didn't make a difference for me

Comment: Deep down in my mind some voice was telling me that single quote can be a problem. However, I told myself single quote/double quote all are same here. But I was so wrong. After trying different things for almost 1 hour, I changed to double quote and voila...

Comment: The reason for this is in the Dockerfile reference: `Note: The exec form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you must use double-quotes (“) around words not single-quotes (‘).`

Comment: Worst 3 hours of my life, trying to figure out why the F it wouldn't find the file, THANKS!, can't stress it enough, THANKS!!

Answer (score 15):

Another source of issues can be your shebang, if you have `/bin/bash` and you don't have bash in your image/base image it will tell your that your entrypoint is not found. This is one of the issues I ran into.

Comment: this was my case as we migrated into alpine distro, so bash needs to be replaced by ash now, just a 'b' of difference

Comment: This, and the upvoted comment above... at first I tried installing `bash` but ultimately the solution for me was to change `bash` to `sh` in my script file: `#!/usr/bin/env sh` ... all the errors I faced up to this point were not this clear lol.

Answer (score 12):

In my case I had an error:

```
> [27/35] RUN /entrypoint.sh:
#31 0.503 /bin/sh: 1: /entrypoint.sh: not found
```

I just run dos2unix command and the issue gone:

```
dos2unix entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: I wish I can upvote a hundred times.

Answer (score 4):

I had a multi-stage build with a golang application where this problem occured. The golang executable was build in builder stage (alpine image) and then copied to the next stage (debian image). In the second stage the error occured: `'mygoexecutable' not found or does not exist.`

The reason was that the executable was not compatible with the image of the second stage due to having some cgo references only available in the builder stage. Afaik apline uses libc and the debian images use glibc. The solution is to use compatible images or to set the environment variable `CGO_ENABLED=0` (disable cgo) while building the executable.

Answer (score 1):

On my case I do try to remove the `EXEC` command from the Dockerfile first to check if the .sh entry file exist. And I confirm that it is there.

When I try to run the .sh from inside the docker container it shows that the .sh file doesn't exist. So I try to run the .sh file using this command `sh /path_to_entrypoint/your_sh_file.sh` and it shows that there is an error in the .sh file.

After some researching I found the answer why there is an error on this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67836849/10835742

Answer (score 1):

If you use a variable in your ENTRYPOINT it might not get resolved.
e.g.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["$WORKING_DIR/start.sh"]
```

This will not do variable substitution.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "$WORKING_DIR/start.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me solution was as simple as adding a new line at the end of `entrypoint.sh` file. I am using Docker on windows (v4.24.0) by the way.

Answer (score -1):

The problem in my case was I used single quote `['/my-entrypoint.sh']` instead of double quotes `["/my-entrypoint.sh"]`.

```
- ['/my-entrypoint.sh']
+ ["/my-entrypoint.sh"]
```

> I can't believe this is 2023 & docker doesn't parse single quotes...