# Docker entrypoint not found although in PATH (and executable)

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint

I am creating a simple image with the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM docker:latest

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin

ENTRYPOINT ['docker-entrypoint.sh']
```

Inside my container:

```
/ # ls -al $(which docker-entrypoint.sh)
-rwxrwxr--    1 root     root           476 Jul 26 07:30 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

So the entrypoint file is **both** in the `PATH` **and** executable;

But when running

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it imageinit
/bin/sh: [docker-entrypoint.sh]: not found
```

I am aware of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460825/entrypoint-file-not-found), but this is about the problem of `PATH` and file permissions (already addressed);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Interestingly your issues seems to be with the type of quotes you have chosen to use. If you change this line:

```
ENTRYPOINT ['docker-entrypoint.sh']
```

to

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

then everything starts to work as expected.

If you check [the documentation for the type of `ENTRYPOINT` you are using](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) all of the examples have double quotes.

I suspect what is happening when you use the single quotes is that docker is parsing this as the shell form of `ENTRYPOINT` and trying to execute a script called `[docker-entrypoint.sh]` which would explain the error message (as obviously no script of that name will exist).

Comment: Extra detail: In the documentation you link to it mentions that the reason for double quotes is because docker parses the value as a json array.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info! This made me think about why when it uses single quotes they are not printed in the error. As I found the answer I though I would share in case it's interesting to anyone else. When docker finds an ENTRYPOINT command it uses [parseEntrypoint](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/instructions/parse.go#L397) which calls parseShellDependentCommand in the same file. This then checks if the command was valid JSON & if not, prepends the shell to the command. So it actually runs `/bin/sh ['docker-entrypoint.sh']` and the shell swallows the quotes

Comment: It's stuff like this that make me wanna quit tech!

Answer (score 3):

I was getting exactly the same error under the same circumstances (although no single quotes problem) when the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script contained carriage returns, converting the script with  `dos2unix docker-entrypoint.sh` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue and the reason i found on another stack over flow answer is line encoding difference, I got my docker file from one of open source project,
and I building and deploying my file on Docker Desktop for Winodw,
I changed my Docker & .sh file encoding from
**CRLF -> LF**  and it worked, you can use VS code for same it have bootom right corner option to convert CRLF to LF.