# No file found when using ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to use `ENTRYPOINT` and whenever I do that I am getting an error as `no such file or directory`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

COPY . /home

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR /home
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I have tried giving it permission, tried running it with absolute path also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460825/entrypoint-file-not-found), tried it with `#!/bin/bash` & `#!/bin/sh` and in the end, I still get the file not found error.

I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: It looks like your docker-entrypoint.sh is in `/usr/local/bin` but you switch with `Workdir` to the `/home` directory. If you want use `docker-entrypoint.sh` in the home directory you have to copy the file to this directory.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem too because when I do `COPY . /home` it also copies this file and the entry point should be able to do it right?

Comment: What's the full error message, and what base image are you using?

Comment: Sorry, updated it. I am using `ubuntu:18.04`

Comment: and the error message os `standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`

Comment: I am able to build it, but I am not able to run it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The question you asked:**
I don't remember exactly why, but the file isn't being found because you're calling it `docker-entrypoint.sh` rather than `./docker-entrypoint.sh`.

**The question you'll ask soon:**
That doesn't entirely fix your problem. You've added execute privileges to the copy of `docker-entrypoint.sh` in `/usr/local/bin`, but there's another copy of the file in `/home` that gets found first and doesn't have execute privileges. You'll get a permissions error when you try to use it. An easy workaround (depending on what you want to do) consists of a modified entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Extra details if you'll be using Docker a lot:**
Being able to enter a container or image to examine its contents is invaluable. For ubuntu-based images, write down the following line somewhere (replace `bash` with `sh` for basically every other linux OS):

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint=bash my_image_name
```

This will open up a shell in that image and let you play around in the same environment the Dockerfile is running in and debug whatever is causing you problems.

Comment: Ya, this did help. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: But now Ican't get into bash with `docker run -ti container bash`

Comment: When you specify an `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile, you need to explicitly override it when running *images*, and the syntax is slightly different than when performing similar maneuvers on *containers*: Compare `docker run -ti --entrypoint=bash image_name` with `docker exec -ti container_name bash`.

Comment: If that's what you're asking? If you're asking about combining ENTRYPOINT and CMD to get default arguments or whatnot, that's beyond the scope of a stackoverflow comment, and you'll want to search for or ask another question and/or read the documentation; the documentation is pretty solid on this one.

Comment: never mind I had to do this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082768/what-does-set-e-and-exec-do-for-docker-entrypoint-scripts