# Docker run does not find ENTRYPOINT

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, docker-entrypoint

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:19.10
WORKDIR /gen
COPY script.sh ./

RUN chmod +x script.sh && export PATH="/gen/:$PATH"

ENTRYPOINT [ "script.sh" ]
```

It builds fine, but I cannot execute it. The solution from [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460825/entrypoint-file-not-found) is to add the full path to the script (`ENTRYPOINT [ "/gen/script.sh" ]`), which does not work.

Adding the folder to `PATH` also does not work. Why is that?

**Error:** `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"script.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

**EDIT:** The problem comes from me calling the container with `docker run --rm -v some/dir:/gen containerName`.

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT [ "/gen/script.sh" ]` works for me.

Comment: I think the problem hast to do with a volume that I am mounting to `/gen`. Could that be the problem @ArkadiuszDrabczyk

Comment: It shouldn't be, `docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/gen container` works for me with `ENTRYPOINT [ "/gen/script.sh" ]` as well.

Comment: What is in `script.sh`? Is that file in your mounted volume? Are you editing the file on windows (check the linefeed type)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you did not modify your `PATH` variable. Using `export` in a `RUN` statement will not be persistent. You need to set environment variables with `ENV`.

```
FROM ubuntu:19.10
WORKDIR /gen
COPY script.sh ./

RUN chmod +x script.sh
ENV PATH="/gen:$PATH"

ENTRYPOINT ["script.sh"]
```

If you run the Docker image while mounting a volume to `/gen`, you will overwrite the `/gen` directory and your script will not be found.

Comment: Thank you very much. The last sentence was the answer I was looking for

Comment: That's great. Because this answered your question, can you please select the green check to mark it as the answer?