# docker-entrypoint.sh: 38: exec: npm: not found

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run `docker run ID npm run test` but I get the following error: `docker-entrypoint.sh: 38: exec: npm: not found`.

I'm very new to Docker and I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460825/entrypoint-file-not-found) (adding the entrypoint `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/api-entrypoint.sh"]`) but it doesn't seem to work.

What do I need to change?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the entrypoint is running on the second image, the nginx one, which does not have npm

Comment: I don't really know what an entrypoint is in Docker or how to properly fix it

Comment: no worries i will try to explain. You are using a multi stage build: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/
in short, you are using an image to perform a couple of actions and then you are copying to a second image something from the first one. An image is just an image like a vm. It does not do anything. If you need to run something when the image is up you need an entrypoint which will execute stuff. I would suggest to creat your image, spin up a container and run manually the entrypoint until you get good results. Then you can copy the entrypoint on build time.

Answer (score 0):

This Dockerfile you've provided was for production purposes. Before that, you built one docker file for the development environment. By creating and running a container using that docker file, you can solve this issue.
I'm guessing your development docker file name is something like Dockerfile.dev. So the solution would be something like,

Building a container

```
docker build -t username/repository-name -f ./Dockerfile.dev .
```

Running that docker container and overriding the primary command using the following command

```
docker run username/repository-name npm run test -- --coverage
```

'username/repository' could be anything you want, it's a conversion to tag your container.